# How to handle stack array allocation failure in C?

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow

If I have to write some code like below:

```
int a[10000000];
```

I know that the code might fail sometimes due to stack overflows. The question is how to handle such errors at runtime, and avoid the segfault?

Comment: Allocate it on the free store.

Comment: An ounce of prevention is worth more than a pound of cure :) Don't allocate the array on the stack, go for the free store right away.

Comment: Why would you have to write code like below (i.e. above)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, stack overflow exceptions are very difficult to handle in a graceful way. This is because the stack is *already* overflowed, and in order for more code (even exception handling code) to run there needs to be stack space available.

In general, programmers design programs so that they cannot overflow the stack. This involves:

- keeping the size of automatic variables allocated on the stack to a minimum (and using other types of allocation if large data structures are needed)
- avoiding unnecessary recursion, and if recursion is used, ensuring that there are reasonable constraints on the maximum depth

If you need space for ten million integers inside a function, don't allocate it on the stack - allocate it using `malloc()` or `new` (depending on whether you are actually using C or C++). Of course it is also your responsibility to `free()` or `delete` it when you are done with it.

If you are really using C++<sup>[1]</sup>, then you should probably be using `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector a(10000000);
```

The underlying standard library implementation will allocate the space on the free store, *and* will automatically deallocate it for you when your function returns.

<sub>[1] I wish people wouldn't tag questions with both [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) just because they are spelled similarly.</sub>

Comment: +Eleventy million for the footnote.  C and C++ are *different languages*, with different goals and philosophies, and what's true for one isn't necessarily true for the other.  It's like tagging a question as both Java and C#.

Comment: I removed C++ tag, although I think there is a stack concept in C++ as well, which is not different from a stack in C.

Comment: @Moeb: Actually, the ISO C standard never mentioned the word "stack". Objects with automatic storage duration are allocated and deallocated in a first-in last-out fashion, but the mechanism is not specified by the language.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to handle this at runtime. The only sane, safe way to use objects of automatic storage duration in C is to keep them small enough that you can be sure they'll never exceed the amount of stack you know you'll have (e.g. never use more than 10% or so of what you expect to have).

Comment: How can one find out the max stack space a program has?

Comment: Unless you're working on an embedded system, it's going to be at least 100k or so, so stick to using significantly less than that and you'll be fine. The best rule of thumb for using the stack is the classic saying "If you have to ask, you can't afford it."